# Play audio files on a guild channel (Not working on Ubuntu Server)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js

I want to make a *"soundboard"* on my Discord Bot.

The bot is currently running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 in a VPS Hosting.

I installed **ffmpeg** via **aptitude** `apt-get install ffmpeg`, and the respective node modules on my project via **npm**: `npm install ffmpeg-binaries --save` and `npm install node-opus --save`

I have this provisional code:

```
//Command syntax: !play (sound)
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('noCorrectSyntax'); //args is provided by module.run

let sound = args[0];
let isReady = true;

if (isReady) {
    isReady = false;
    let voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('noChannel');

    voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>{
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile(`../resources/audios/${sound}.mp3`);
        if (!dispatcher) return message.channel.send('soundNotFound');

        console.log(`Playing ${sound} on ${message.member.voiceChannel.name}`);

        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
            voiceChannel.leave();
            console.log(`Finished`);
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    isReady = true;
} else {
    return message.channel.send('botNotAvailable');
}
```

When my bot joins the voice room, it leaves instantly without playing the sound.

Am I doing something wrong by installing the **ffmpeg** codec this way? Is a problem with the VPS?

(I tried with a new bot, installing **ffmpeg** on windows and setting the environment variable path and it worked fine)

**EDIT:**

I listened for the "error" and "debug" events on the *StreamDispatcher* (as specified in https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher?scrollTo=e-error), but I don't receive errors or debug info.

When I listen for the "speaking" event, is showed on my console as `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was I dind't take care about the working directory specified by the process. I thought it will work from the actual file position on the filesystem.

I use a index.js to run commands on separate files, like this:

```
let commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}`);
commandFile.run(discord, fs, etc ...);
```

And on each command file I put this code:

```
exports.run = async (discord, fs, etc ...) => {CODE FOR THE COMMAND};
```

That was the problem. As *Splingush#7845* explained me on the official **Discord.js support server**: *"Sounds like you had an issue with relative paths, when you do `../resources/audios/${sound}.mp3`"*

**From `fs`:**
"Relative paths will be resolved relative to the current working directory as specified by process.cwd()" (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths).

Then, the only thing I had to do is rewrite this line to look like this:

```
const dispatcher = connection.playFile(`./resources/audios/${sound}.mp3`);
```